# parse the array from file

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a problem when reading an array from a file. how can this be done in a stream? I need to count the whole string and put it in the Student fields

// # Name Surname Marks

// 1 Mike Scott [4,5,5]

// 2 Joe Jones [1,2,3]

```
class Student6 {

int ID;
String Name;
String Surname;
Integer[] marks;

public Student6(int ID, String name, String surname, Integer[] marks) {
    this.ID = ID;
    Name = name;
    Surname = surname;
    this.marks = marks;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path1 = "C:\\Users\\Professional\\IdeaProjects\\Lesson\\src\\StreamAPI\\FileStream";
    List<String> stream1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(path1)).toList();
    String[] arr = new String[stream1.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stream1.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = stream1.get(i);
    }

    List<Student6> student4s = Stream.of(arr)
            .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
            .map(l -> {
                String s = l.split(" ")[3];
                String[] chars = s.split("");
                Integer[] integers = new Integer[3];

                for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                    if (chars[i].matches("[0-9]")) {
                        int c = 0;
                        integers[c++] = Integer.parseInt(chars[i]);
                    }
                }
                out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
                return new Student6(Integer.parseInt(l.split(" ")[0]), l.split(" ")[1], l.split(" ")[2],
                        new Integer[]{1, 1, 1});

            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Comment: Just let your int c = 0 out of for loop.

Comment: Don’t use a `Files.lines(…)` Stream without closing it. If you want to get a list of lines, use [`Files.readAllLines(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)). On the other hand, as the answer mentions, there is no point in copying the entire stream into a `List`, followed by manually copying the list into an array (`List` has both, `toArray(…)` and `stream()`), just to call `Stream.of(…)` with the array, to get a Stream of lines like you already had after `Files.lines(…)`

Answer (score 2):

`Files.lines` returns a `Stream<String>` and so you can chain the stream methods directly on it.

I've rewritten the `map` step to parse the fields of the Student from the read line.

It parses the marks from the string of format `[mark-1, mark-2..., mark-n]` by first removing the leading and trailing braces (`[` and `]`). Then it splits the string on `,` and converts each mark to an Integer.

In your code, there is an attempt to check the extracted mark against a regex (`[0-9]`). It is not clear what is to be done if a mark/score is not an Integer and hence I've skipped it assuming we have valid data.

```
List<Student6> students;
try (Stream<String> fileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path1))) {
    students = fileStream.filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
            .map(line -> {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                String marksData = parts[3];
                String marksAsString = marksData.substring(1, marksData.length() - 1); // remove '[' and ']'
                String[] marks = marksAsString.split(",");
                   
                return new Student6(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]),
                        parts[1], parts[2],  Arrays.stream(marks)
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .toArray(Integer[]::new));
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```